# No Audio From HDMI?

Tags: centos, audio, nvidia, hdmi, asus

I am using CentOS 7.9 and I have Asus H110M-E (which has built-in audio and video) and GeForce GT 710 video card with the driver installed via `yum`:

```
(1/4): nvidia-x11-drv-470.103.01-1.el7_9.elrepo.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | 4.5 MB  00:00:02     
(2/4): kmod-nvidia-470.103.01-1.el7_9.elrepo.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |  48 MB  00:00:03     
(3/4): yum-plugin-nvidia-1.0.2-1.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |  12 kB  00:00:00     
(4/4): nvidia-x11-drv-libs-470.103.01-1.el7_9.elrepo.x86_64.rpm
```

And I am not using the latest (version 510) because Nvidia removed support after version 470 for GeForce GT 710.

I am trying to use GeForce GT 710's HDMI to output the audio as well to my Samsung TV.

However, there is no audio (but video).  And I looked into `dmesg`, and these lines look fishy:

```
[    3.194768] asus_wmi: Disabling ACPI video driver
[    3.218574] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    3.218576] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    3.226895] alg: No test for __gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-gcm-aes-aesni)
[    3.226930] alg: No test for __generic-gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-generic-gcm-aes-aesni)
[    3.242290] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.242459] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    3.242464] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    3.265463] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: irq 125 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.300528] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC887-VD: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    3.300532] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.300534] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    3.300536] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    3.300538] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x11/0x0
[    3.300540] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    3.300542] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[    3.300544] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[    3.300546] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
[    3.301579] kvm: disabled by bios
[    3.314616] kvm: disabled by bios
[    3.316354] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    3.316358] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    3.316360] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    3.316362] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    3.330539] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
[    3.332496] kvm: disabled by bios
[    3.332523] hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
[    3.333055] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0xfdffe800-0xfe0007ff], which spans more than pnp 00:07 [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdffffff]
[    3.333058] caller pmc_core_probe+0x8f/0x1000 [intel_pmc_core] mapping multiple BARs
[    3.333065] intel_pmc_core:  initialized
```

It seems like the HDMI audio on GeForce GT 710 is suppressed.  Is there a way to fix it?

`aplay` detects HDMI audio device (tho I am not sure whether it is my video card or the builtin video device on my motherboard):

```
$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Another way to look at the detected sound cards:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7220000 irq 125
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17
```

`lspci` also sees my Nvidia card as an audio device:

```
$ lspci | grep -i "NVIDIA"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: does https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gtx-1060-no-audio-over-hdmi-only-hda-intel-detected-azalia/53463/7 help?

Comment: So did you try to use the NVidia HDMI? You need to select the output both under Pulseaudio and ALSA. If you did, what exactly did you do, what happened?

Comment: @dirkt  Thanks for your suggestion.  I just ran `alsamixer` and selected "HDA Nvidia" card, and "F5 (All)" only showed two items: `S/PDIF` and `S/PDIF 1`.  Any suggestion?

Comment: @Bib  thanks for the link.  I looked at the post.  It is a bit different -- the OP there showed that `lspci` didn't find the Nvidia card as an audio device.  However, `lspci` found my nvidia card as an audio device (I just updated my post).

Comment: HDMI codecs typically don't have a mixer, so that's not unexpected. Have you tried to **use** it? Assuming you really don't run Pulseaudio (unusual today), do `aplay -L`, see what devices you have with `plughw` or `hw` for HDMI, find a WAV file with the right sample right, use `aplay -D ...` to play it. None of this will work if you do run Pulseaudio, in that case just run some application that plays some sound, and use `pavucontrol` to select the output.

Comment: Or use `speaker-test` for the ALSA case.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I did try to use chrome to play some video on youtube.  but I got no sound.  tho, using the analog line-in from the builtin sound card works (connecting to a PC speaker).  I will try out you suggestions in 2 hours.  Thanks.

Comment: @dirkt `pavucontrol` is the silver bullet -- I selected `hdmi` device as the output, now the sound works!  Mind writing it up as an answer?  I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually select the output. Under Pulseaudio, you can do this with `pavucontrol` for applications, even if the application itself doesn't support it.

Comment: thanks.  just a related question -- after selecting the source, it seems like the choice might not be persisted (i.e. after reboot or the application restart, it is gone).  any idea?

Comment: The choice is usually persisted by a Pulseaudio module maintaining a database by application name. If that doesn't work out of the box on your system, you'll need to debug where it is broken, which needs a lot of familiarity with Pulseaudio...

Comment: got it.  then is there a way to set HDMI as the primary output source for all applications?

Comment: You can usually set the **default** output (again using `pavucontrol`) that will apply to any applications not yet in the database. That won't override the applications already in the database, though.